# Facing Error - We couldn't find the record you're trying to access in lightning community

Tags: community, lightning-experience, process-builder

While saving a contact on the community. I am getting the above error

> Error - We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask your administrator for help.

I have written as process builder on Contact which updates the contact owner to system admin.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Below is the debug logs of PB - 
09:05:13.232 (301277347)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_DETAIL|09L0n00000099Tj|[Contact: sdfc test 0030n00000dssjB]|Id=09L0n00000099Tj|CurrentRule:Update_Contact_Owner3010n0000007Np1 (Id=01Q0n000000E3Ua)
09:05:13.232 (301634075)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_DETAIL|Param Name: myVariable_current, Param Value: ENCODED:{![treatNullAsNull]{!ID:this}}, Evaluated Param Value: {Entity type: Contact, id: 0030n00000dssjBAAQ}|Param Name: myVariable_old, Param Value: {!old}, Evaluated Param Value: null

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected outcome when a record's owner is changed in such a way that the context user no longer has visibility on that record.

Say for example (as I am assuming is the case here) you have the Org-Wide Default for Contact set to Private. You're logged in as User A, who does not have See All Data permission or See All on the Contact object. You create a Contact and press Save.

Your Process Builder then executes and changes the owner of the Contact to a System Administrator, who's not below User A in the role hierarchy. At this point, unless User A has some other route to visibility on that Contact, he/she no longer has the right to see that record.

As far as the save process goes, that's fine - it completes successfully and returns control to the user, who's redirected to the page where they should be able to see the Contact they just saved. Except... they no longer have the right to see that record, and so this error will naturally result.

If the user is meant to retain visibility on the Contacts that they create, a change to the sharing and visibility architecture is called for. Conversely, if the desire is just to provide a smooth user interaction, one route could be to use a Flow to create the contact rather than the native New Contact action. This would allow you to guide the user to a preferred landing page and provide messaging around the record create process, even though the user doesn't get to see the results.

Comment: Thank you @David Reed. Is there any way I can make the contact to be saved in the community on a custom object which has lookup to contact and after that 3-4 sec I will change the owner. Can we do that from Process builder or Trigger? I want to create it corresponding portal user also once the contact is created and I have assigned the portal account to it.

Thank you for your help in Advance!

Comment: That's a much bigger question that I cannot answer in a comment. You may need a separate post with details. You can, however, perform delayed actions using Scheduled Actions in Process Builder.

Comment: Sure but scheduled action in process builder are of hours or days...However, I need for seconds only.

Comment: Then you have to go to Apex.

Comment: Is it possible from a trigger?

Comment: You can't control executing at second resolution on the Salesforce platform. You can use a future method to defer beyond a transaction, but it could execute in seconds or minutes. You can use Schedulable Apex to target a specific minute. This is really a separate question, though. If you need more details, please make a new post.

Comment: David - Can you please help here posted here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247869/getting-error-while-creation-of-contact-in-community